# Javascript: Line Break after first comma

Tags: javascript

I have an address that is being pulled from database that interacts with Google Map API. When displaying results my address renders as follows:

456 Here Street, City, AL 36723

What would be a solution for entering a line break after

> 465 Here Street

So that the address would display as

```
456 Here Street
City, AL 36723
```

Comment: Are you trying to replace the "first occurrence" of `,` into a line break, or "magically" convert a single line address into "correct" multiple lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var address = "456 Here Street, City, AL 36723";

address = address.replace(',', '<br/>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BvT9p/

Answer (score 2):

```
address.replace(",", "\r\n");
```

Where address is your address as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
"456 Here Street, City, AL 36723".replace(',','\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var address = '456 Here Street, City, AL 36723'; //however you acquire the address
var addressArray = address.split(',');
var addressNode = document.createElement('address');

addressNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(addressArray[0]));
addressNode.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
addressNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(addressArray[1] + ',' + addressArray[2]));
```

I'd avoid using innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:-

```
  string.match(/.{,}/g).join("<br/>");
```

or try this:-

```
 address.replace(",", "\r\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the first comma with br tag:

```
var str = "456 Here Street, City, AL 36723";
str.replace(/,/, '<br />');
```